# How do i move a sprite that's animated

Tags: python, pygame

So i recently started trying to make a game. Im having trouble moving the player that is animated. I have it flip through a sprite sheet for the animation i just dont know how to have that animation move around the screen. So I just need to know how i can move an animating image. In the game I have a running animation and a idle animation i want it to switch to the running animation when i hold a arrow key and do the running animation while moving across the screen. Then go back to the idle animation while not moving.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Rocket_Jump')

width = 1750
height = 1250
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

#FPS
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Black Gunner
bg_idle_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'Rocket_Jump\TeamGunner_By_SecretHideout_060519\CHARACTER_SPRITES\Black\Gunner_ Black_Idle.png').convert_alpha(); bg_idle_frames = 5
bg_run_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'Rocket_Jump\TeamGunner_By_SecretHideout_060519\CHARACTER_SPRITES\Black\Gunner_Black_run.png').convert_alpha(); bg_run_frames = 6
bg_crouch_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'Rocket_Jump\TeamGunner_By_SecretHideout_060519\CHARACTER_SPRITES\Black\Gunner_Black_crouch.png').convert_alpha(); bg_crouch_frames = 3
bg_death_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'Rocket_Jump\TeamGunner_By_SecretHideout_060519\CHARACTER_SPRITES\Black\Gunner_Black_death.png').convert_alpha(); bg_death_frames = 8
bg_jump_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'Rocket_Jump\TeamGunner_By_SecretHideout_060519\CHARACTER_SPRITES\Black\Gunner_Black_jump.png').convert_alpha(); bg_jump_frames = 2

#Background
BG = (178, 190, 181)

#start position
start_x = 100
start_y = 100

#Gets images from a sprite sheet
def get_image(sheet, frame, width, height, scale, color):
image = pygame.Surface((width, height)).convert_alpha()
image.blit(sheet, (0, 0), (frame * width, 0, width, height))
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (width * scale, width * scale))
image.set_colorkey(color)
return image


#Animation
class  Gunner(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, sheet, frames, pos_x, pos_y, type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.sprites = [get_image(sheet, i, 48, 48, 4, 'Black') for i in range(frames)]
        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.rect.center = [self.x, self.y]
        self.type = type

    def update(self):
        self.current_sprite += 1
        if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

run = True


while run:
    #What keys are pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player_idle = Gunner(bg_idle_sheet, bg_idle_frames, start_x, start_y, 1)
    player_run = Gunner(bg_run_sheet, bg_run_frames, 100, 100, 2)
    moving_sprites.add(player_idle)
    moving_sprites.add(player_run)

    #Screen color
    screen.fill(BG)

    #Quit Program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        for sprite in moving_sprites: 
            if sprite.type == 1: 
                start_x += 1
                sprite.draw(screen)
            elif sprite.type == 2:
                sprite.draw(screen)

        

    moving_sprites.update()
    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your animated sprites move, I would recommend you use the built-in functions for pygame rectangles like the move function instead of updating the start_x on each iteration of the game loop:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip

Also you should make the Gunner object only once before the game loop and not re-create the same thing every iteration. Eventually your game will start to lag because of this once you add more to the game.

For transitioning between animations, I would highly recommend that you start with making only one instance of your Gunner object, and it contains all of the animations. Instead of two gunner objects where each gunner has only 1  set of images. For example you can have your Gunner.sprites be structured like

```
self.sprites = {
    "running" : [get_image(bg_run_sheet, i, 48, 48, 4, 'Black') for i in range(bg_run_frames)],
    "idle" :  [get_image(bg_idle_sheet , i, 48, 48, 4, 'Black') for i in range(bg_idle_frames)]
}
```

Then you can keep track of the gunner's state in a variable, and key into this dict depending on your state. To manage the state, in the gunner's update function if there's a KEYDOWN event, you run, KEYUP, you go idle etc